# How to loop a cloned object in python?

Tags: python, loops

This is my first question posted on here and I am very new to coding so please excuse me if I'm doing this wrong!  I am using the graphics library to create a house.  I am making a fence, and there is one shape that is repeated multiple times, and just moved to the right 17 pixels. I am using the graphics library by John Zelle.

```
import graphics as g
win = g.GraphWin("Welcome Home", 500, 500)

fencePost = g.Polygon(g.Point(3, 340), g.Point(8, 335), g.Point(13, 340), g.Point(13, 370), g.Point(3, 370))
fencePost.setFill('white')
fencePost.setOutline('white')
fencePost.draw(win)

fencePostTwo = fencePost.clone()
fencePostTwo.move(17, 0)
fencePostTwo.draw(win)

fencePostThree = fencePostTwo.clone()
fencePostThree.move(17, 0)
fencePostThree.draw(win)

fencePostFour = fencePostThree.clone()
fencePostFour.move(17, 0)
fencePostFour.draw(win)
```

Above is what is have in my code...literally 25 times.  I tried to make it into a function, below, which I thought would loop through the sequence to create 10 fence posts, but when I run it, nothing happens. Any pointers? Thank you!

```
def newFence():
    sequence = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150]
    sequenceMultiplier = 1
    for index in range (len(sequence)) :
        newFencePost = fencePost.clone()
        newFencePost.move(sequenceMultiplier, 0)
        newFencePost.draw(win)
newFence()
```

Comment: Hi Allie, Welcome. It would be useful if you tell us which graphics library you are using. In your code sample include the import statement which imports 'g'. Also it would help a little if you expand on why it doesn't work (how is the behaviour different to what you expect)

Comment: @MattyW Yeah what's `g`??????????

Comment: @MattyW I updated it! I am using John Zelle's graphic library.  I wanted the function to loop through the sequence and create 10 fence posts, but it won't happen. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is to repeat the following code 25 times, each time using the next clone:

```
fencePostTwo = fencePost.clone()
fencePostTwo.move(17, 0)
fencePostTwo.draw(win)
```

The simplest thing to do is to rename the variables and put them in a loop:

```
current_fence_post = fencePost
for i in range(25):
    current_fence_post = current_fence_post.clone()
    current_fence_post.move(17, 0)
    current_fence_post.draw(win)
```

Or, if you want to have it in a function, you can do this:

```
def make_shifted_clone(win, obj, offset_x, offset_y):
    cloned_object = obj.clone()
    cloned_object.move(offset_x, offset_y)
    cloned_object.draw(win)
    return cloned_object
```

And then:

```
next_post = fencePost
for i in range(25):
    next_post = make_shifted_clone(win, next_post, 17, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in the logic, you are not using the numbers in the sequence array.
You need to use it in the move statement, something like this will work:

`newFencePost.move(sequenceMultiplier * sequence[index], 0)`

It would be more pythonic to just iterate the sequence and use its numbers, changing the for for something like

```
for offset in sequence:
...
```